# Best moment to trigger sounds in 2D games

Tags: 2d, game-design, godot, sound, sound-effects

As a test project I am creating a 2D tower deffense game in Godot (C#). My question is about best practices in the industry on how to manage sound effects.

One of the enemies is represented by an Orc that is an SpriteAnimation with different animations like idle, walk, run or attack. Right now, after falling from sky, the enemy is "running" to the tower until there's a collision with it and then it starts the "attack" animation which is simply a hammer hit. My question is about the sound associated to the hit, should it be played when the animation ends? is there any other practice over there to handle this?

Comment: If it is a hit (as opossed to attack) wouldn't it better be playing when the tower takes damage and not be based on the attack animation.

Comment: logically the hammer hit sound should be played at the moment when the hammer hits the tower.

Comment: @Nikaas and, when does the tower gets the damage? at the end of the animation? I'd need to detect that which I honestly don't know because that end its triggered multiple times (I guess because it's FPS based)

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb is not to annoy the player with sounds. That's why in tower defense games enemy characters don't have walking sounds(just imagine the ammount of noise the army would create). About your question. I would play the sound when the collision had happened. This way the player will know that the orc is braking/broke the tower. To implement this try raising an event when collision happens, in the godot case try using signals(https://godotengine.org/article/csharp-ios-signals-events).

Comment: It's a good idea. Don't you feel like some sound is still missing? If we take a different type of game as example, like Clash Royale, every character has a hit sound on each hit to enemy towers, that makes the experience better definitely.

Comment: You mentioned your enemies fall from the sky, for interactivity you could add a falling sound

Comment: Clash Royal does not have the amount of troops compared to a classic tower defense game

Comment: If your game uses panning and zooming, one idea is to only make the sounds noticeable when the players is zoomed in close to the action. Factorio does this.